# OpenCV Error: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV, and attempting to use OpenCV for Python 3.7 to stitch five images together into one singular image. The source code I originally used only allowed for two images to be stitched together, so I had to modify it to allow five webcam images to be stitched. However, I am presented with this error:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\colby\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\photomosaic.py", line 80, in <module>
>       img3 = cv2.drawMatches(kpsA,secondImg,kpsB,thirdImg, kpsC, forthImg, kpsD, fifthImg, kpsE, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
>   TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'`

**My Code:**

```
  import cv2
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import imageio
   import imutils
   import cameracapture
   cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
   feature_extractor = 'orb' # one of 'sift', 'surf', 'brisk', 'orb'
   feature_matching = 'bf'
   firstImg = imageio.imread('cap1.jpg')
   firstImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(firstImg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   secondImg = imageio.imread('cap2.jpg')
   secondImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(secondImg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   thirdImg = imageio.imread('cap3.jpg')
   thirdImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(thirdImg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   forthImg = imageio.imread('cap4.jpg')
   forthImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(forthImg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   fifthImg = imageio.imread('cap5.jpg')
   fifthImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(fifthImg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

   plt.show()
   def detectAndDescribe(image, method=None):   
       assert method is not None, "You need to define a feature detection 
method. Values are: 'sift', 'surf'"

    if method == 'sift':
        descriptor = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    elif method == 'surf':
        descriptor = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
    elif method == 'brisk':
       descriptor = cv2.BRISK_create()
    elif method == 'orb':
       descriptor = cv2.ORB_create()

    # get keypoints and descriptors
    (kps, features) = descriptor.detectAndCompute(image, None)    
    return (kps, features)
kpsA, featuresA = detectAndDescribe(firstImg_gray, method=feature_extractor)
kpsB, featuresB = detectAndDescribe(secondImg_gray, method=feature_extractor)
kpsC, featuresC = detectAndDescribe(thirdImg_gray, method=feature_extractor)
kpsD, featuresD = detectAndDescribe(forthImg_gray, method=feature_extractor)
kpsE, featuresE = detectAndDescribe(fifthImg_gray, method=feature_extractor) 
def createMatcher(method,crossCheck):
     if method == 'sift' or method == 'surf':
     bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=crossCheck)
 elif method == 'orb' or method == 'brisk':
     bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=crossCheck)
 return bf
 def matchKeyPointsBF(featuresA, featuresB, featuresC, featuresD, featuresE, method):
    bf = createMatcher(method, crossCheck=True)

    # Match descriptors.
    best_matches = bf.match(featuresA,featuresB)
    best_matchs = bf.match(featuresA,featuresB + featuresC + featuresD + featuresE)

    # Sort the features in order of distance.
    # The points with small distance (more similarity) are ordered first in the vector
    rawMatches = sorted(best_matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
    print("Raw matches (Brute force):", len(rawMatches))
    return rawMatches
def matchKeyPointsKNN(featuresA, featuresB, featuresC, featuresD, featuresE, ratio, method):
    bf = createMatcher(method, crossCheck=False)
# compute the raw matches and initialize the list of actual matches
    rawMatches = bf.knnMatch(featuresA,featuresB, featuresC, featuresD, featuresE, 2)
    print("Raw matches (knn):", len(rawMatches))
    matches = []

    # loop over the raw matches
    for m,n in rawMatches:
        # ensure the distance is within a certain ratio of each
        # other (i.e. Lowe's ratio test)
        if m.distance < n.distance * ratio:
            matches.append(m)
    return matches
print("Using: {} feature matcher".format(feature_matching))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

if feature_matching == 'bf':
    matches = matchKeyPointsBF(featuresA,featuresB, featuresC, featuresD, 
featuresE, method=feature_extractor)
    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(kpsA,secondImg,kpsB,thirdImg, kpsC, forthImg, 
kpsD, fifthImg, kpsE, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
elif feature_matching == 'knn':
    matches = matchKeyPointsKNN(featuresA,featuresB, featuresC, featuresD, 
featuresE, ratio=0.75, method=feature_extractor)
    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(firstImg,kpsA,secondImg,kpsB,thirdImg, kpsC, 
forthImg, kpsD, fifthImg, kpsE, np.random.choice(matches,100),

None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)


plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()
  def getHomography(kpsA, kpsB, kpsC, kpsD, kpsE, featuresA, featuresB, 
  featuresC, featuresD, featuresE, matches, reprojThresh):
        # convert the keypoints to numpy arrays
    kpsA = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kpsA])
    kpsB = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kpsB])
    kpsC = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kpsC])
    kpsD = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kpsD])
    kpsE = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kpsE])

    if len(matches) > 4:

    # construct the two sets of points
    ptsA = np.float32([kpsA[m.firstIdx] for m in matches])
    ptsB = np.float32([kpsB[m.secondIdx] for m in matches])
    ptsC = np.float32([kpsC[m.thirdIdx] for m in matches])
    ptsD = np.float32([kpsD[m.forthIdx] for m in matches])
    ptsE = np.float32([kpsE[m.fifthIdx] for m in matches])
        # estimate the homography between the sets of points
        (H, status) = cv2.findHomography(ptsA,ptsB,ptsC,ptsD,ptsE, cv2.RANSAC, reprojThresh)

        return (matches, H, status)
    else:
        return None
M = getHomography(kpsA, kpsB, kpsC, kpsD, kpsE, featuresA, featuresB, 
featuresC, featuresD, featuresE, matches, reprojThresh=4)
if M is None:
    print("Error!")
(matches, H, status) = M
print(H)
# Apply panorama correction
width = trainImg.shape[1] + queryImg.shape[1]
height = trainImg.shape[0] + queryImg.shape[0]

result = cv2.warpPerspective(trainImg, H, (width, height))
result[0:queryImg.shape[0], 0:queryImg.shape[1]] = queryImg

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(result)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
# transform the panorama image to grayscale and threshold it 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Finds contours from the binary image
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

# get the maximum contour area
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# get a bbox from the contour area
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

# crop the image to the bbox coordinates
result = result[y:y + h, x:x + w]

# show the cropped image
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(result)
```

**The expected output:**

> I expect the program to be able to take five pictures with my webcam (which is imported through **cameracapture**), and then stitch them together to make one image. Any advice or fixes to this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check how to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem in order for the community to be able to help.

Comment: That error message looks a bit broken (I'd expect the %s to be replaced by the actual parameter name) -- which exact version of OpenCV is this? Might be worth reporting on the OpenCV issue tracker.

Comment: Now, looking at `cv2.drawMatches(kpsA,secondImg,kpsB,thirdImg, kpsC, forthImg, 
kpsD, fifthImg, kpsE, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)` and crosschecking with the docs... That doesn't really fit the [documented parameter list](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d4/d5d/group__features2d__draw.html#ga62fbedb5206ab2faf411797e7055c90f). For one, the first two pairs of image and keypoint arguments seem swapped (compare with your second call to `cv2.drawMatches`). The next 5 parameters seem completely out of whack.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this so the code can work?

Answer (score 1):

```
 firstImg = imageio.imread('cap1.jpg')
 print(type(firstImg))
```

if the output is

```
<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
```

Then covert it to an array using:-

```
firstImg = np.asarray(firstImg)
```

Load this firstImg to convert it to gray scale image